# Getting Wireless Card To Work Old Fujitsu Siemens Laptop

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-networking, drivers, wireless-adapter

I'm working on a project bringing computers to a settlement in South Africa, and have a bunch of old donated laptops that I am trying to get into working order.  This one is a Fujitsu Siemens Amilo, and I've reinstalled a fresh copy of XP and all the drivers, but the wireless card is not working, even after downloading the updated drivers.  Further info:

- Wifi adapter (built in) is: intel pro wireless 2200bg
- Driver version 9.0.39
- Laptop Model Amilo M7440
- Wireless connection icon has an X through it and says "Not Connected"
- If I "View Available Wireless Networks" and refresh, nothing shows up even when I'm right next to the router.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you confirmed the WiFi adapter isn't broken, or that it's antennas haven't come detached?

Comment: It shows up as working in the device manager.  There is nothing physical sticking out of the laptop with antennas, and no place they would have been broken off.  I'm pretty sure the adapter is internal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  I had to install the power manager, which then made the wireless on / off button work:

http://support.ts.fujitsu.com/download/ShowDescription.asp?SoftwareGUID=F75C5146-A2E3-4D04-BFDA-FB41E0D89323